# How do I get a list of all members in a discord server, preferably those who aren't bot

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I'm attempting checks if a username is in a valid username in the server. The check is done by the following code

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!logan',
                   intents=intents,
                   helpCommand=helpCommand)
Users = [# Need help getting users]


async def Fight(ctx, User):
  if ctx.author.name != User:
    if User in Users:
      open_file = open(str(ctx.author.name), "w")
      open_file.write(User + "\n300\nTurn")
      open_file.close()
      open_file = open(User, "w")
      open_file.write(str(ctx.author.name) + "\n300\nNot")
      open_file.close()
      await ctx.author.send("You are now fighting " + User)
      #await ctx.User.send("You are now fighting " + ctx.author.name)
    else:
      await ctx.send("User is not in this server")
  else:
    await ctx.send("You Cannot Fight Yourself")
```

I've tried googling, but I haven't found a valid answer

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to get your guild name, but here's a possible method to get it and get the member list from it.

In `member` (and `user` so), there is the ".bot" that is a boolean, 0 if not a bot.

```
listMembers = []

@bot.command(name="init")
async def FuncInit (ctx) : 
     global listMembers
     guilde = ctx.message.guild
     for member in guilde.members : 
          if not member.bot : 
               listMembers.append(member.name)
```

Comment: List comprehension could be used to shorten the code: `notBots = [m for m in ctx.message.guild.members if not m.bot]`.

Comment: @caTS I don't know but it's possible it works too, I'm not yet into the "all in one line" logic :D